# Finding a branch for a square root functions

Tags: complex-analysis

How can we define a branch for $\sqrt{ 1 + \sqrt{z} } $? I know a branch for $\sqrt{z}$ is the negative real axis. But, how can we deal with the square root of $1+ \sqrt{z} $ ?

Comment: You only need a branch when what's under the radical can be zero. If you take the negative real axis as the branch for $\sqrt z$, then $1+\sqrt z$ can't be zero, so no further branch-taking is needed.

Comment: So, we can take this branch for $\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{z} }$ and so it is analytic outside of it?

Comment: Sure looks like it.

Comment: the more interesting question would be how to handle a minus sign under the square root..